# Call async function in a sync way in Dart

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await

I have this function, want to call it synchronously, because if I call it async then I should use FutureBuilder, which I don't prefer because it has extra flicker if user scrolls too fast:

```
Future<String> getRealHTML(int chapter) async {
    var key = _Html.keys.toList()[chapter];
    var val = _Html.values.toList()[chapter];
    if (val.Content.startsWith("filename:")) {
      EpubContentFileRef value = contentRefHtml[key];
      return await value.readContentAsText();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: *"I have this function, want to call it synchronously"* - no, you cannot do that

Comment: help me to understand, you want to call it without waiting for it in UI correct !

Comment: The thing with `Future`s is that nothing calling them can be synchronous. You need to find ways to work with them. Maybe use a fade-in effect to remove the flicker? Or maybe fetch the data earlier so that it's instantly available at the point of displaying it. The optimal solution depends on your exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

`readContentAsText()` returns a `Future`, you cannot call it synchronously since it is an I/O request which means it will take time to finish the request, that is why it is called asychronously.